# How to know if array / object is empty after delete function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

```
var arr = [30];
delete arr[0];
if (arr.length == 0) {
alert("empty");
}
```

This code won't work only because of delete. 
Is there an ultimate way to check if the array is empty no matter what?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why not use `splice` or `pop` or `shift` to remove items? `delete` is not really the best tool for taking items off an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind the expected behaviour is that when you use the `delete` operator, it replaces the element by `undefined`, and since the length doesn't change the above check does not work.

One of the ways to effectively delete an element from the array is to use the `filer` `array function`.

Example:

```js
function deleter(arr, toDelete) {
  let newArray = arr.filter((ar) => {
    return ar !== toDelete;
  })
  return newArray;
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5]

console.log(deleter(array, 5));
```

Now to check if an element exists in an array, you can use the `indexOf` method available on the `array` `prototype`.

Following is an example:

```js
    function deleter(arr, toDelete) {
      let newArray = arr.filter((ar) => {
        return ar !== toDelete;
      })
      return newArray;
    }

    let array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    let toDelete = 5;
    
    let newArr = deleter(array, toDelete);
    
    console.log(newArr.indexOf(toDelete))
    
    // -1 corresponds to the element not found.
```

Comment: "it replaces the element by `undefined`" - it actually really deletes the property. `arr.hasOwnProperty(0) === false`. It just doesn't update the length, which may be a bit confusing, as e.g. assignment already changes the length automatically: `let arr = []; arr[3] = 1; arr.length === 4;`. This is slightly odd, as traps for property deletion are even possible on proxies already. The spec somehow just says 'The "length" property of an Array instance is a data property whose value is always numerically *greater* than the name of every configurable own property whose name is an array index.'

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks for the clarification, I didn't actually mean it 'replaces' the value, added the line just for the sake of simplicity, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values()` to get actual values from the array. If the length of the values array is 0, then the array is empty by your definition.

```js
const checkIfSparseIsEmpty = arr => !Object.values(arr).length

var arr1 = [30];
delete arr1[0];

console.log(checkIfSparseIsEmpty(arr1)) // true

var arr2 = [1, 2, 3]
delete arr2[0]
delete arr2[1]

console.log(checkIfSparseIsEmpty(arr2)) // false

console.log(checkIfSparseIsEmpty(Array(10))) // true
```